# Static UNC "shortcut" to network folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, smb

Is there a way to create a path like `\\this_never_changes\static` that maps to some arbitrary network location, in the same fashion as mapping a drive letter? I can't just map a drive letter, since I am using a program that stores network paths as UNC and misbehaves if something gets moved to a different server.

Comment: When you map a drive letter, you map to a UNC path like \\servername\foldername.  You can generally use that same UNC path in place of the mapped drive.

Comment: The problem is if I have something on `server1` and it moves to `server2`, then my program loses track of the file and the path needs to be updated in hundreds of places.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected I was missing something here. In this case, I wonder if symbolic links would do the job for you. This article refers only to Win10, but MKLink is available at least as far back as Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably easier to use an NTFS directory junction link for this.

You can do the following in an administrator command prompt:

```
mklink /D C:\path\to\networkFolder \\networkMachine\folder
```

Then when the network folder location changes it is simply

```
del C:\path\to\networkFolder
mklink /D C:\path\to\networkFolder \\otherNetworkMachine\folder
```

The `path\to\networkFolder` should be a folder that does not currently exist on your system, but is where you now want to set your program to use.

In this way you can simply close the program, reset the network location link (again, as administrator) and then relaunch the program.